# CLLocationCoordinates from locationManager didUpdateLocations

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager, cllocationcoordinate2d, uber-api

I am trying to use CoreLocation (once permission is granted) to get a user's CLLocationCoordinate2D, so that I can pass that information to an Uber deeplink (after a UIButton within my TableView is pressed).

I've figured out how to get the coordinates as CLLocations, and turn them into CLLocationCoordinates2D in the didUpdateLocations method, but can't seem to transfer them over to my buttonPressed function.

Can anyone explain how I can properly transfer the coordinates info to the uberButtonPressed method? I am also confused about how to get the locationManager to stop updating location once a suitable location is determined. Any help is much appreciated. By the way I am using this to instantiate Uber: https://github.com/kirby/uber

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation
import MapKit

class ATableViewController: UITableViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    var location: CLLocation?
    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D?

// Implemented tableView methods etc here...

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {
    let newLocation = locations.last as! CLLocation
    println("DID UPDATE LOCATIONS \(newLocation)")
    location = newLocation
    coordinate = location!.coordinate
    println("WE HAVE THE COORDINATES \(coordinate!.latitude) and \(coordinate!.longitude)") // this prints along with DID UPDATE LOCATIONS        
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didFailWithError error: NSError!) {
    println("error:" + error.localizedDescription)
}
    func uberButtonPressed(sender: UIButton!) {
        let senderButton = sender
        println(senderButton.tag)

        let authStatus: CLAuthorizationStatus = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()

        if authStatus == .NotDetermined {
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
            return
        }
        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        }


        var pickupLocation = coordinate! // fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

        println(pickupLocation)

//            // Create an Uber instance
//            var uber = Uber(pickupLocation: pickupLocation)
//        
               // Set a few optional properties
//            uber.pickupNickname = "OK"
//        
//            uber.dropoffLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 47.591351, longitude: -122.332271)
//            uber.dropoffNickname = "whatever"
//            
//            // Let's do it!
//            uber.deepLink()
//            
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move `var pickupLocation = coordinate!` into your `didUpdateLocations`. Once assigned, you can call `locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()` also from inside `'didUpdateLocation` or your value for coordinate with keep updating. After stopping the locationManager, call a NEW function to run the rest of your code currently in `func uberButtonPressed`

Comment: Hi thx for input... I tried moving pickupLocation to didUpdateLocations and this worked, I am getting the coordinate and implemented  stopUpdatingLocation() correctly. I am a little confused as to what you mean by calling a NEW function to run the rest of the code in func uberButtonPressed... Do you mean I should take out the code (from uberButtonPressed) - starting from var uber = Uber(pickupLocation: pickupLocation!), make a separate function and then call it from didUpdateLocations? I've tried this and pickupLocation is still nil ... Problem may be that uberButtonPressed runs 1st?

Comment: Yes, that is correct, you should call a new function after you have stopped your location updates. The new function would include the code starting from `var uber = Uber(pickupLocation: pickupLocation!)`  You can either pass your `pickupLocation` to the new function or make `pickupLocation` a property of your class so it can be read from your new function after it gets assigned a value in the `didUpdateLocation`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

Instead of calling the delegate method like this:

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {
    debugPrint("NOT CALLED-- didUpdateLocations AnyObject")    
}
```

I changed into:

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    debugPrint("CALLED-- didUpdateLocations CLLocation")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are unwrapping `coordinate` which is a `CLLocationCoordinate2D?` with a `!`.  Since coordinate is from location which is a `CLLocation?`.  It is possible that coordinate is nil and location is nil, especially before location services have had a chance to kick in.  Only run the rest of `uberButtonPressed:` for the case where coordinate and location are not nil by using `if let currentCoordinate = coordinate?`, and in that case, call `locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()`.